# Why is it called the Millennium Falcon?

Tags: star-wars, millennium-falcon

I'm particularly interested in how the "Millennium" part pertains to the ship itself. It wouldn't hurt to explain the "Falcon" part either though.

Comment: Because if it was called the '***Century Dodo***', kids wouldn't have queued up to buy one.

Comment: It'll all be explained in a very unsatisfying way in the Han Solo movie. It'll probably turn out that young Leia met young Han and named the ship after some sort of microscopic particles that make smugglers be great smugglers and Han's millenniumfalconium-rate is through the roof.

Comment: It helps to realize its the fourth version of the ship, the previous ones being the *Annual Falcon*, the *Decade Falcon* and the *Century Falcon*. The next version, the *Aeon Falcon*, is apparently quite an improvement....

Comment: Finally, I am the first to post the relevant xkcd https://xkcd.com/890/

Comment: [What the hell is an aluminum falcon?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3F1d3QWsyk0)

Comment: @Valorum Okay, that's actually hilarious.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The Millennium Falcon has a long history, explained on [Wookieepedia and I would strongly encourage you to read it here](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Millennium_Falcon).

The important part on that page is the below quote:

> The *Second Chance* [the Millennium Falcon before it was rechristened] was briefly rechristened the *Gone to Pieces* during
>   this operation, but when he began flying the ship for the Alliance, he
>   rechristened her **the *Millennium Falcon*, after the bat-falcon**

Just to note, in the above quote, Wookieepedia explains that 'he' is [Zenn Bien](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Zenn_Bien) who had stolen it, however [this source](https://worldofjaymz.fandom.com/wiki/Millennium_Falcon) makes it sound like it was Quip Fargil who rechristened it the *Millennium Falcon*, but also agrees it was after a 'bat falcon'.

Now a 'bat falcon' was:

> a swift species of flying creatures. It inspired the name of the
>   starship Millennium Falcon.

([Source](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Bat-falcon))

That explains the 'falcon' part; as for the 'Millennium' part of the name, I suspect (note that I don't have any evidence for this, but I think it's a reasonable speculation) that it was named so because 'Millennium' sounded futuristic; consider when *Star Wars* was released - it wasn't too far from the turn of the millennium, but far away enough to make it seem very futuristic.  Just my thoughts on this part, but I'll keep on looking to try and find any evidence in this regard.

Comment: The Wookiepedia info, I believe, comes from the 2008 book *Millenium Falcon* by James Luceno, and is not canon.  Still, I think this is the best answer that exists since I'm not aware of any canon material that gives the history of the name.

Comment: @Rori Thanks for that info.  I wasn't entirely sure of the origin of it but I figured seeing as though the OP didn't specify the level of anon required I'd post this ;)

Comment: Absolutely.  I think this is the best that's out there.  We don't really have that much canon info on MF's history other than how Han acquired it from Lando and we know it was around as early as Revenge of the Sith since it made a cameo in the film.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/890/

Comment: @Rori: Unfortunately, the circumstances around how Han won the MF from Lando ("Rebel Dawn" by Ann C. Crispin, and "Lando Calrissian and the Starcave of ThonBoka" by L. Neil Smith) is no longer canon, either.  The only canon reference remaining is a line in "The Empire Strikes Back". Lando: *"What have you done to my ship?"* Han Solo: *"YOUR ship? Hey, remember **you lost her to me, fair and square**."*

Comment: @N_Soong: I was commenting on Rori's comment that your answer is not official canon anymore. It applies to the Legends canon, not the new Disney canon. And in the "Revenge of the Sith" cameo, we don't actually know who is flying the MF at that point.

Comment: @RemyLebeau My bad!

Comment: A bat falcon is a real bird found in the Neotropics.

Comment: If you update this answer to include Disney canon, I will consider awarding it a bounty.