# Is the name Millennium Falcon a reference to FALCON codes?

Tags: star-wars, millennium-falcon

Has Lucas ever given any reason to think the name "Millennium Falcon" is an indirect reference to US military aviation FALCON codes?

From [here](http://www.combat.ws/S4/SAILOR/APNDX3.HTM) we see that FALCON 1000 means "Cool it, the Chaplain's here" or, [here](http://www.fighterpilotuniversity.com/history/nature-of-the-beast/falcon-codes/), "Cool it the Padre is here".

Note that religion is a common StarWars subtext, and the Millennium Falcon is often trying to escape the "Father".

Also, I could have *sworn* I remember Han saying "Cool it" at some point but I can't find any proof of that.

Somewhat related to [Why is it called the Millennium Falcon?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/98974/why-is-it-called-the-millennium-falcon) but that seems to be asking for a in-universe answer, whereas I want a behind-the-scenes answer.

Comment: The link to religion seems *very* weak to me.

Comment: Is there any special reason you think it might be, or is this just your own pet fan-theory?

Comment: pet fan-theory :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. I can find no evidence that the Millennium Falcon's name was inspired by, or a reference to, FALCON codes.

Additionally, I searched all three Original Trilogy transcripts and found no instance of Han saying "Cool It."

Also, when the Millennium Falcon was first named (before *A New Hope* was filmed) Darth Vader was not Luke's father.

Answer (score 1):

It's highly unlikely that there's a link such as you suggest.  A far more likely behind-the-scenes answer has to do with speed (emphasis mine):

> The [peregrine [falcon]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peregrine_falcon) is renowned for its speed, reaching over 322
>   km/h (200 mph) during its characteristic hunting stoop (high speed
>   dive), making it the **fastest member of the animal kingdom**.

which ties in to:

> **Han Solo**: Fast ship? You've never heard of the Millennium Falcon?
>
> **Ben Obi-Wan Kenobi**: Should I have?
>
> **Han Solo**: It's the ship that made the Kessel Run in less than twelve
>   parsecs. I've outrun Imperial starships. Not the local bulk cruisers
>   mind you, I'm talking about the big Corellian ships now. She's fast
>   enough for you old man. What's the cargo?

(quote from [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0000002/quotes))

Comment: Can the peregrine falcon do the tropics to Mercia run in under 12 leagues?

Comment: African or European?

Comment: @Xantec I don’t think that particular run has been measured, but from a book I proofread on peregrine falcon migration stats (yes, you read that right), female peregrines have been measured as travelling from the Thule region in northern Greenland to various places in South America in impressively short times. One travelled about 12,500 km in just 15 days, and another travelled 1,349 km in one day. I think if we convert that to futuristic far-in-the-past intergalactic parsecs, we’ll find they compare quite favouribly to the _Falco Millennialis_ subspecies.