# In Disney canon, what is the origin of the name of the Millennium Falcon?

Tags: star-wars, millennium-falcon

What is the origin of the Millennium Falcon's name,  *within Disney canon*?

Obviously the falcon is in reference to the bat-falcon (as per [Why is it called the Millennium Falcon?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/98974/why-is-it-called-the-millennium-falcon)) but what about the 'millennium' part?

Comment: I'm looking specifically for Disney Canon only.

Comment: @richard does that question cover Disney Canon?

Comment: As far as I'm aware,  there's no explanation within the Disney Canon, period.

Comment: Voted to reopen; not a duplicate, since this question is restricted to Disney canon.

Comment: @SQB I think that it is the same either way.